# MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 max key allow?

Tags: encryption, php

maximun key for MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 ?

mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, <<==hash_hmac using sha512==>>, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv )

Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm in C:\xampp\htdocs\natabuana.com\cpanel\encryption.php on line 18

Comment: Do you have a good reason to choose rijndael 256 over AES?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a HASH_HMAC of SHA-512, yielding 512 bits, while the max key length you can use is 256 bits. Change your HMAC to 256.